# Remove array from json object stored in SQL Server column

Tags: json, sql-server

If I have the following JSON stored in a column in SQL Server:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{"id": "1", "name": "test1"},{"id": "2", "name": "test2"},{"id": "3", "name": "test4"}]'
```

how can I remove an array where Id:=1 ?

I want to get the following result:

```
[{"id": "2", "name": "test2"},{"id": "3", "name": "test4"}]
```

Comment: Does this JSON end up in the application tier? If so, I think you might have better luck stripping there using something trivial like a LINQ statement (assuming this is a .NET solution)?

Comment: are you using sql server 2016?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    declare @json nvarchar(max) = '[{"id": "1", "name": "test1"},{"id": "2", "name": "test2"},{"id": "3", "name": "test4"}]';


    DECLARE @IdTobeRemoved INT =1;
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT
    DECLARE @EndIndex INT
    DECLARE @tempjson nvarchar(max)



    SELECT @StartIndex = CHARINDEX('"id": "'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@IdTobeRemoved)+'"',@json)-2


    SELECT @tempjson = STUFF(@json, 1, @StartIndex, '')


    SELECT @EndIndex = 
                CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@tempjson,CHARINDEX('}',@tempjson)+1,1)=']'
                    THEN CHARINDEX('}',@tempjson)+1
                    ELSE CHARINDEX('}',@tempjson)+2
                END


    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@json,SUBSTRING(@tempjson,0,@EndIndex),''),'},]','}]')
```